# How to get the dimensions of a DOM element, minus border and padding?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the size of the content-box of a `<div>` (or any other element) using **pure JavaScript**? By content-box, I don't mean the size of text inside the div, I mean the element's on-screen size minus border and padding.

[image: An element's bounding boxes]

This is what I see in Chrome Dev Tools. I want just the blue part (720 x 540) in JavaScript. My problem with `offsetHeight` and company is that they return the dimensions of the black solid rectangle in the graphic (it's hard to see -- between margin and border).

Note that the `width` and `height` CSS properties may or may not be set; I want the dimensions regardless. Further note that padding and border may or may not be consistent (it might have only one border, for example).

Answer (score 11):

`element.clientWidth` will give you the width including padding (but no border).

Then, you can `parseFloat` the values of `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`. Here is an example:

```
 function getElementContentWidth(element) {
  var styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  var padding = parseFloat(styles.paddingLeft) +
                parseFloat(styles.paddingRight);

  return element.clientWidth - padding;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the second radix argument to `parseFloat`, only for `parseInt`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: What about you have `padding:2rem` that not `px` as unit?

Comment: @JamesYang it'll still return in px

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that seems to work correctly and is fairly well-supported. But I will still accept other answers that do not require parsing numbers out of strings. There has to be another way!

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(my_div);
var width = parseFloat(style.width);
var height = parseFloat(style.height);
```

Comment: wrong. it gives you the width WITH the padding. this is unwanted.

Comment: @vsync It appears to get CSS `width` and `height`, which generally don't include padding unless you have `box-sizing: border-box`. Can you create a small demo of this behavior?